# How to call reload parameters of Router in ionViewDidEnter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I'm doing an Ionic Application with the version 4, and I'm trying to do something. I have one page (HomePage) and a button, on this page I send parameters to another page (MapPage) with the class Router, with the NavigationExtras (state), and it is working, because I receive the parameters in MapPage in the constructor with this code:

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
```

And it is working well, but the problem is when I want to send another data to the MapPage, because this page is already rendered and the constructor has been already called the first time, so when I want to send another data (because I have a ion-list in HomePage, and each item has different data, I can't receive data because the constructor has been already invoked the first time.

I want to get the data in the ionViewDidEnter if it possible, to get an updated data each time that I send from the HomePage with the NavigationExtras, but I don know how to do that.

I hope that you can help me, or if you know a best way to do it, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get navigation data from `history` object:

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
    const historyState = history.state
}
```